# Pegar valor de input radio exibir na mesma página, sem refresh

Tags: php, javascript, input

Não consigo pegar o valor do tipo de frete que o usuário escolhe e exibir ele na mesma página no box de finalização da compra.

Esta é a página que o usuário digita o frete[image: Pagina que mostra o frete e a finalização da compra]

```
<div class="delivery">
                                <div class="section_title">Calcule o frete</div>
                                <div class="section_subtitle">Entregue pelos Correios</div> 
                                <div class="coupon_form_container">
                                    <div class="coupon_form">

                                    <input type="text" class="coupon_input" placeholder="Digite seu CEP" id="frete_cart" name="frete_cart" required="required">
                                    <button class="button coupon_button" ><span>Calcular</span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="resposta" id='resposta'></div>


                </div>

<li class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                                <div class="cart_total_title">Frete</div>
                                <div class="cart_total_value ml-auto">AQUI VAI O VALOR DO FRETE ESCOLHIDO</div>
                            </li>

<script> //calculo frete
var frete_cart = $("#frete_cart"); 
    frete_cart.change(function() { 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'calcularFrete.php?peso=<?php echo $peso ?>&total=<?php echo $total ?>', 
            type: 'POST', 
            data:{"frete_cart" : frete_cart.val()}, 
            success: function(data) { 
            console.log(data); 
            data = $.parseJSON(data); 
           // $("#resposta").text(data.email);
           //$("#submit").attr("disabled", true);

            $("#resposta").html(data.frete_cart);


        } 
    }); 
});
```

calcular Pagamento.php

```
if(isset($_POST['frete_cart'])){ 
include('conn.php');



$peso = $_GET['peso'];
$valor = (int)$_GET['total']; // transforma o valor do produto em inteiro

#Recebe o cep de destino
$cepDestino = $_POST['frete_cart'];

if(isset($cepDestino)){ // se existir o cep de pesquisa faz a consulta

$sedex = (calcular_frete('88960000', $cepDestino, $peso,$valor,'04014'));
$pac = (calcular_frete('88960000', $cepDestino,$peso,$valor,'04510'));

// $exibe ="<p>Receba em até " . $sedex->PrazoEntrega . " dias úteis: " . $sedex->Valor . "</p> <p> Receba em até " . $pac->PrazoEntrega . " dias úteis: " . $pac->Valor . "</p>" ;


        $exibe ="<div class='delivery_options'>
                        <label class='delivery_option clearfix'>Receba em até  " . $sedex->PrazoEntrega . " dias úteis. 
                            <input type='radio' name='frete' id='frete'  value='". $sedex->Valor ."'>
                            <span class='checkmark'></span>
                            <span class='delivery_price'> R$ ". $sedex->Valor . "</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class='delivery_option clearfix'>Receba em até  " . $pac->PrazoEntrega . " dias úteis: 
                            <input type='radio' name='frete' id='frete'  value='". $pac->Valor ."'>
                            <span class='checkmark'></span>
                            <span class='delivery_price'> R$ " . $pac->Valor . "</span>
                        </label>

                    </div>



                    ";




echo json_encode(array('frete_cart' => $exibe)); 
}
}
```

Como faço para quando o usuário escolher uma das opções de frete ou o valor será exibido na mesma página, sem precisar atualizar? .................................................. ..................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeira coisa é que você não deve repetir o mesmo `id` em mais de um elemento. Um `id` deve ser único. Veja que você colocou o `id="frete"` nos dois radios. Remova esses id's porque não é nem necessário usar `id` nos radios nesse caso. Você pode selecionar os radios pelo `name` ou pela classe da div onde eles estão, que é `.delivery_options`.

Seria interessante colocar o `id="frete"` na div que irá receber o valor:

```
<div id="frete" class="cart_total_value ml-auto">AQUI VAI O VALOR DO FRETE ESCOLHIDO</div>
```

Isso porque essa div só possui classes, e como outro elemento pode vir a ter uma dessas classes, irá dar problema.

Você irá selecionar os radios da seguinte forma, passando o valor para a div `#frete`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".delivery_options :radio", function(){
   $("#frete").html(this.value);
});
```

**Veja um exemplo:**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".delivery_options :radio", function(){
   $("#frete").html(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='delivery_options'>
   <label class='delivery_option clearfix'>Receba em até  5 dias úteis. 
      <input type='radio' name='frete' value='36,80'>
      <span class='checkmark'></span>
      <span class='delivery_price'> R$ 36,80</span>
   </label>
   <br>
   <label class='delivery_option clearfix'>Receba em até  8 dias úteis: 
      <input type='radio' name='frete' value='32,48'>
      <span class='checkmark'></span>
      <span class='delivery_price'> R$ 32,48</span>
   </label>
</div>
<h2>Frete</h2>
<div id="frete" class="cart_total_value ml-auto"></div>
```

Comment: Funcionou corretamente obrigada! Porém como faço para armazenar o dado em uma variável? para poder junto com o subtotal fazer o total da compra. Obrigada!

Comment: Pode fazer assim: `let frete = 0; $(document).on("click", ".delivery_options :radio", function(){ frete = parseFloat(this.value.replace(",", "."));
   $("#frete").html(this.value);
});`. A variável `frete` será, por exemplo, `36.80` (um ponto no lugar da vírgula para pode somar posteriormente com outro valor).

Answer (score 1):

se deseja que o valor do frete seja mostrado após clicar no input radio correspondente, basta criar um script sobre a ação da seleção:

```
$('#frete').change(function (event) {
    $("#resposta").html(data.frete_cart);
});
```

Dessa forma o valor da div resposta será alterada assim que selecionado o frete, sem refresh da página.